# SharePoint SPFX (No Framework) How to call function from onclick

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I am not using React or anything like that. I want to add a onclick function to a  like this:

```
<tr onclick="rowclick(id)">
```

I have a public function:

```
public rowClick(id): void {
  console.log(id);
}
```

How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add class or attribute to tr so you could bind as

```
this.domElement.querySelector('tr.MyTR').addEventListener('click', () => { alert('123') });
```